# Greedy Algorithm Giving Dubious Results

Tags: java, algorithm, math, greedy, cs50

I am implementing a simple greedy algorithm:

**Aim:** To pay-back the user's change using as few coins as possible out of the following coin types; *Quarter* (0.25), *Dime* (0.10), *Nickel* (0.05) & *Penny* (0.01).

**Input:** The amount of change the user is owed.

**Output:** The total number of coins used in paying-back the user.

A snippet of my code can be seen below:

```
final double quarter = 0.25d;
final double dime = 0.10d;
final double nickel = 0.05d;
final double penny = 0.01d;
double changeOwed;
int coinsUsed = 0;

/*
Code to get the user's input
*/

    while (changeOwed > 0 && changeOwed % quarter != changeOwed) {
        coinsUsed++;
        changeOwed -= quarter;
    }

    while (changeOwed > 0 && changeOwed % dime != changeOwed) {
        coinsUsed++;
        changeOwed -= dime;
    }

    while (changeOwed > 0 && changeOwed % nickel != changeOwed) {
        coinsUsed++;
        changeOwed -= nickel;
    }

    while (changeOwed > 0 && changeOwed % penny != changeOwed) {
        coinsUsed++;
        changeOwed -= penny;
    }

    System.out.println("Change remaining: "+ changeOwed);
    System.out.println("Total coins used: "+coinsUsed);
```

---

### Results:

```
Enter change owed: 32
Change remaining: 0.0
Total coins used: 128
```

---

```
Enter change owed: 3.25
Change remaining: 0.0
Total coins used: 13
```

---

```
Enter change owed: 0.32
Change remaining: 3.469446951953614E-18
Total coins used: 4
```

---

I decided to do this using while loops, and the modulo operator. If `changeOwed` were equal to 0, then there would be no need to execute the while loop, because all of the change would've been paid-back. To add to this, if `changeOwed % COINTYPE` ("COINTYPE" being an arbitrary placeholder) were equal to changeOwed, this would indicate that COINTYPE is greater than `changeOwed` (the amount of remaining change). In such an event, the program proceeds to he next while-loop sporting a smaller COINTYPE.

As can be seen above, the algorithm seems to produce the correct output as regards the amount of coins used. However, as in the last example, the amount of change remaining seems to be way off. I understand that computers cannot do perfect arithmetic due to a finite number of bits. However, ***why is it that the amount of change remaining has increased drastically from 0.32 to 3+?***

Comment: In general, for money calculations it is better to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Wouldn't `changeOwed % quarter != changeOwed` be better written as `changeOwed >= quarter`. It's clearer on intent, and runs faster (no division). It will also fix the rounding issue you're having.

Comment: Next, try to write the code without use of loops.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 3. Its 3E-18 which is a very small number (0. 18-zeros 3).

This is probably caused by using `doubles`. [It's a floating point error.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

If you want to avoid this use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 1):

3.469446951953614E-18 is a very small number. It is **not** the scale of 3.0.

Comment: Oh, I see... I feel silly now haha. So is it so that the algorithm itself actually correct? The problem lies solely with floating-point arithmetic?

Comment: I actually didn't read the algorithm, I concentrated on your description of the problem... What I can say is, this problem doesn't require any loops, simple arithmetic will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about coins and change, there is no need to use real numbers here. Instead of BigDecimal, you can just use long, and compute everything in the number of cents, not the number of dollars.